# Displaying records from the table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The code to draw, transfer and delete a record already written.
But I do not know how to do to the records displayed the.

The basic idea is:

```
    $mysqli->query("SET @ROW_ID := (SELECT id FROM klucz ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);");
    echo  $mysqli['game'].  $mysqli['steam'].  ;
```

Here is the entire code:

```
        {

        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "klucze");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}



/* set autocommit to off */
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

/* Insert some values */
$mysqli->query("SET @ROW_ID := (SELECT id FROM klucz ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);");

    echo  $mysqli['game'].  $mysqli['steam']. "Wylosowana gra to: <BR>Twoj kod do gry:" ;



$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO kluczuzyty SELECT * FROM klucz WHERE id = @ROW_ID;");



/* commit transaction */
$mysqli->commit();

/* drop table */
$mysqli->query("  DELETE FROM klucz WHERE id = @ROW_ID;");







/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: `echo $mysqli['game']`? That's impossible. `$mysqli` is your database handle, and NOT where your query results get stored.

Comment: you need to loop over the results.

Comment: Could you write me what I have to change? :(

Comment: `while ($row = (fetched from your query)) { echo "something"; }` - `foreach` is another method. There are ample examples on the web.

Comment: @fred-ii- How to reduce while?

Comment: what do you mean by that; plus an example of expected results

Comment: `while ($row = ($mysqli->query("SET @ROW_ID := (SELECT id FROM klucz ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);"))) {



    echo  $row['game'].  $row['steam']. ;



$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO kluczuzyty SELECT * FROM klucz WHERE id = @ROW_ID;");



/* commit transaction */
$mysqli->commit();

/* drop table */
$mysqli->query("  DELETE FROM klucz WHERE id = @ROW_ID;");

return 0;
}
` you do not see the results :(

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab at this, but it still does not make a lot of sense.
**EDIT** I think I understand what you're trying to do now. Take a look.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "klucze");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* set autocommit to off */
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

if($results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM klucz WHERE ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")){
    while($row = $results->fetch_Assoc()){
        $ROW_ID = $row['id'];
    }
    // Edited after comment
    $results->free();
}
if(isset($ROW_ID)){
    if($results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM klucz WHERE id = $ROW_ID");
        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
            echo  "{$row['game']}{$row['steam']}Wylosowana gra to: <BR>Twoj kod do gry:";
        }
        $results->free();
    }
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO kluczuzyty SELECT * FROM klucz WHERE id = $ROW_ID;");
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM klucz WHERE id = $ROW_ID;");
}
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: What about it does not work? What errors are you seeing? It was untested and only a part of your code, so I do not know what it is doing.

Comment: I edited my code, it became more clear what I think you're trying to do. Find a random `ID` and then get some data from that record. Then copy that entire record to the other table, and remove it from the first table. There are caveats to doing this. You will encounter rows that are out of order since they have been deleted. The `IF` statements will help, yet you will need to try again if it is false or no `ID` is returned.